# How to write Multiplicative Update Rules for Matrix Factorization when one doesn't have access to the whole matrix?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, gradient-descent, matrix-factorization

So we want to approximate the matrix A with m rows and n columns with the product of two matrices P and Q that have dimension mxk and kxn respectively. Here is an implementation of the multiplicative update rule due to Lee in C++ using the Eigen library.

```
void multiplicative_update()
{
Q = Q.cwiseProduct((P.transpose()*matrix).cwiseQuotient(P.transpose()*P*Q));
P = P.cwiseProduct((matrix*Q.transpose()).cwiseQuotient(P*Q*Q.transpose()));
}
```

where `P`, `Q`, and the `matrix` (matrix = A) are global variables in the `class mat_fac`. Thus I train them using the following method,

```
void train_2(){
double error_trial = 0;
for (int count = 0;count < num_iterations; count ++)
    {
        multiplicative_update();
        error_trial = (matrix-P*Q).squaredNorm();
        if (error_trial < 0.001)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

where `num_iterations` is also a global variable in the `class mat_fac`.

The problem is that I am working with very large matrices and in particular I do not have access to the entire matrix. Given a triple (i,j,matrix[i][j]), I have access to the row vector P[i][:] and the column vector Q[:][j]. So my goal is to write rewrite the multiplicative update rule in such a way that I update these two vectors every time, I see a non-zero matrix value.

In code, I want to have something like this:

```
void multiplicative_update(int i, int j, double mat_value)
{
Eigen::MatrixXd q_vect = get_vector(1, j); // get_vector returns Q[:][j] as a column vector

Eigen::MatrixXd p_vect = get_vector(0, i); // get_vector returns P[i][:] as a column vector

// Somehow compute coeff_AQ_t, coeff_PQQ_t, coeff_P_tA and coeff_P_tA. 


for(int i = 0; i< k; i++):
        p_vect[i] = p_vect[i]* (coeff_AQ_t)/(coeff_PQQ_t)
        q_vect[i] = q_vect[i]* (coeff_P_tA)/(coeff_P_tA)  

}
```

Thus the problem boils down to computing the required coefficients given the two vectors. Is this a possible thing to do? If not, what more data do I need for the multiplicative update to work in this manner?

Comment: What about using a `Eigen::SparseMatrix` to hold `matrix`?

Comment: In our project, we are not holding matrices in the memory.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want. Could you perhaps provide a (working!) implementation (i.e., a [mcve]) of what you would do if all matrices fit into memory? And then say which parts you need to/want to modify?